# Differentiate $L=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |\gamma_{i+1}-\gamma_i|$ with respect to $\gamma_i$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, proof-explanation

I am reading “A Glimpse into Discrete Differential Geometry” by Keenan Crane and Max Wardetzky, and I couldn’t understand how they computed the derivative of $L$ with respect to $\gamma_i$.

[image]

For a polygonal curve, we can simply differentiate
the sum of the edge lengths $L=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}  |\gamma_{i+1}-\gamma_i|$ with respect to any vertex position. At a vertex $i$, we obtain

$$\partial_{\gamma_i} L=  \frac{ \gamma_i - \gamma_{i-1}}{| \gamma_i - \gamma_{i-1} |}- \frac{ \gamma_{i+1} - \gamma_{i}}{| \gamma_{i+1} - \gamma_{i} |} =T_{i-1,i} - T_{i,i+1}$$
Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the key thing to understand is that the gradient of the function $f(x)=\|x-a\|$ is the unit vector $\dfrac{x-a}{\|x-a\|}$. (The function increases most rapidly radially away from $a$, and it changes at a rate of $1$ unit per unit moved, obviously, when you move radially.) The formula you inquired about is just applying this with $x=\gamma_i$.

Comment: It’s exactly what I am asking about. Thank you!